# Creating new layer from selection in QGIS

Tags: qgis, select-by-attribute, select-by-location, query-layer

Is it possible to create layers from selection in QGIS? I am using QGIS 1.7.4-Wroclaw.

To make it easier for others to see this, here are some pics. I used QGIS 2.0.1-Dufour.

**Selecting**
[image]

**Saving**
[image]

**Adding**
[image]

Comment: It works a similar way to ArcGIS see johns answer. See more and more user/clients want to switch to QGIS- it is comparable to ArcView license and direct connect to PostGIS makes it better than ArcGIS in my book.

Comment: If QGIS works similar to ArcGIS, I guess I will not have tough time switching

Comment: @Mapperz Can you please suggest me place where  I can find standard tutorials? Googling does not seem to give me any comprehensive resource.

Comment: [QGIS Documentation](http://www.qgis.org/en/docs/) site has the [QGIS User Guide](http://www.qgis.org/en/docs/user_manual/index.html), or the [QGIS 2.0 Training Manual](http://manual.linfiniti.com/LinfinitiQGISTrainingManual-en.pdf) is in the works by Linfiniti.

Comment: Is it possible in QGIS 2.0? I can't find the way.

Comment: @JúlioCésar, yes you can do it. Please see my updates in my posted question.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

After making a selection in a layer, right click on it and choose save selection as.

---

#### Update for QGIS 3.2 Bonn as of 2018

As this is the accepted answer and the way of doing this has evolved somewhat, beginners might find this answer incomplete, so:

After making a selection in a layer, right click on it and choose "Export" > "Save Selected Feature As..."

[image: menu selection]

which is actually just a nice redundancy, because it takes you to the same mask as clicking "Save Feature As...", but it already checks the box "Save only selected features"

[image: Save Vector Layer As Mask]

Comment: Note that you can make a selection using the 'select' tool, but also can run queries directly on a layer with a right-click and selecting "Query..." and then construct a search (which will then hide items that don't match). "Save as" will then save just the displayed features.

Comment: Using can be much quicker if you have lots of features that are spread out over the map.  Saves selecting them one at a time, or using the inbuilt search.

Comment: @johns that isn't the same as making a layer on a selection ... what you've described is saving a new shapefile entirely...

Comment: Thank you for updating the answer, made things much simpler to find :)

Answer (score 20):

A new feature [just came up in QGIS 2.2](http://changelog.linfiniti.com/qgis/version/21/#) called "Paste as new vector layer":

> It is a common activity in a GIS to create a sub-selection and then to create a new layer from the selection. In QGIS you can already do
>   `save selection as` to save a layer from your selection, and now
>   offers functionality that allows you to create a new file or memory
>   layer from whatever is in your clipboard. Simply select some features,
>   copy them to your clipboard and then do `Edit -> Paste features as`
>   and choose either `New vector layer` or **`New memory layer`** from
>   the submenu. The best part of this new feature is that if you have
>   some Well Known Text (WKT) features in your clipboard from another
>   app, you can simply paste them into QGIS as a new layer now.

Comment: `New memory layer` is the trick

Comment: That is a great tool - thanks for sharing, very helpful!

Comment: Sadly, it has some unlisted limits - i.e., it works if I select, say, 100 points from a vector layer but if I select some 20000 points then copying to clipboard fails silently.

Comment: Which is the difference between "new vector layer" and "new memory vector layer"?

Comment: When you copy a selected feature and paste as a new vector layer, it will open the 'save layer as' dialogue box and save as a new shapefile. New Memory Vector layer only persists in the QGIS document (and will persist when you open it next time if you have the memory layer saver plugin installed) @AndreuAmoros

Comment: For anyone else as confused as I was that "Paste as new layer" opens a dialog asking you questions you don't have the answers to - the correct option paste the selection to a new layer* is given the utterly baffling name "Paste as > *Temporary scratch layer*" in my version of QGIS. "Paste as layer" actually means what everyone else in this quadrant of the galaxy would call "Save selection to new file".

Answer (score 12):

In QGIS 2.6.2 Brighton, you can do the following:

1. Select features
2. Right click on the layer
3. Save as...
4. Select the option "Save only selected objects"
5. Save

That should do

Comment: The "save selection as..." feature has been deprecated in favor of this new method - so this answer is now the correct way to save selected features to a new layer.

Comment: This also works for 2.8 Wien

Answer (score 6):

Or right-click on the layer, choose "Query", and write a SQL construct.  This is analagous to creating a "Definition Query" in ArcGIS if you do not want to write a new shapefile to disk.

Comment: that still isn't the same as the arcgis 'save selection as layer' concept... If you do an ArcMap query or set of queries and end up with a selected set, how would you replicate that in a new layer based on a "query" in QGIS? I just don't think the same ability is in QGIS as in ArcMap - not saying it *should* be...just saying its not there.

Comment: An update for anyone who comes across this and finds this answer helpful, as I did.  In QGIS 2.2, right-click on a layer and choose "Filter" and write a SQL statement.

Answer (score 1):

I actually miss the older version's option to `Save selection as new layer`. I'm using QGIS 2.6.0 Brighton and using `Edit > Paste options as` just doesn't work. 
One attempted workaround was to create a new layer, then paste features into that layer, however this does not appear to have copied any attribute data for me.

Therefore my solution has been to:

1. Copy desired layer.
2. Make my selection.
3. Open attribute table.
4. Invert selection.
5. Delete unwanted features.
6. Save.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using QGIS 2.10.1-Pisa. To save selected features with PyQGIS, you can try the following:

```py
import processing
##Once selection has been done
#Layer which contains selected features
layer= iface.activeLayer()
#Specify where you want to save your new file (in my case)
result='C:\Users\Desktop\Test\selected.shp'
#Using geoprocessing alg "Save selected features"
processing.runalg('qgis:saveselectedfeatures', layer, result)
#Add saved file to map
processing.load(result)
```

Reference: https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_general_tools/saveselectedfeatures.html

Answer (score 0):

In QGIS 2.18.17, make the selection using either a filter or manual selection then right-click on the layer in the Layer Panel, then select 'Save As'. As you only want to save the selection select the tick-box for selection only.