# Saving selection as new layer in QGIS 2.4?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2.4

I've selected a number of polygons from one layer and want to create a new layer. Because I can't right click using a mac how do I find "Save Selection As". Its not in the list in the "Layer" drop-down from the top toolbar.

I'm using QGIS 2.4 with Mac OS X 10.9.4.

Comment: I've found how to right click on the layer but the Save Selection option still isn't listed there, have I installed it incorrectly?

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to include the additional information that you just posted as a comment, please?

Comment: @PolyGeo: The old question is not a duplicate, because `Save selection As` has moved from the context menu to the `Save As ` dialogue in QGIS 2.4.

Comment: @AndreJoost On your advice I've now retracted my vote for http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26198/how-to-create-a-new-layer-from-a-selection-in-qgis being a duplicate

Answer (score 13):

You can right click with a Mac, hold 'ctrl' and click. Or use two fingers to tap on the touch pad, or plug in a mouse with two buttons.

When you do that, you right click your layer (that has selected items) and choose 'save as' then check the box 'save only selected features.'

[image: Save Selection As in QGIS]

Comment: Note that this behaviour has changed from QGIS 2.2 to 2.4. The old `Save Selected As` has been dropped (not only for Mac users).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your selection is by `expression`. In QGIS 2.18.20 you can view ONLY the selection by `right-clicking on the Layer > properties > General > Query Builder`. then you enter the expression you wish to select for here.

If you wish to have both the original layer and the selection in your files, a hack will be to duplicate the layer and perform the selection on one.