# Why is the data missing in my new shapefile?

Tags: qgis, export

I've made a new shapefile from a part of an attribute table. Marked all the rows that I needed and clicked on "save selection as", added the new layer in my project. All the data is missing, there is only the headlines of the columns.

I save the new shapefile like this:

- Format: ESRI shapefile
- Encoding: System
- Layer CRS
- And the same projection as all the other layers, SWEREF99 12 00.

I'm used to working in ArcMap, and I'm now working in QGIS. Is there a difference in the programs of how I do this kind of thing?

Comment: What version of QGIS are you running? In 2.4, the 'save as' context menu loads the 'save vector layer as' dialogue, which has a check-box for 'save only selected features'...

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26198/how-to-create-a-new-layer-from-a-selection-in-qgis Duplicate? Perhaps in QGIS, as with ArcMAP, when you export from the attribute table, it creates a new 'table' (csv, xls, etc...) and does not copy the shape information.

Comment: I have 1.8, know there is newer versions than this. Working in county and I'm not allowed to install newer versions myself, I got also told that i might get problems with projects that I'm working in for the moment if i got a newer version in the middle of it.

Comment: Using 1.8 you have two options, Save Selection as... or Save as... the second option will "export" all your features/rows. QGIS 1.8 is a bit old, lot's of features and performance improvements have been added in later versions. I strongly advice you to request your IT team for an update.

Comment: While that hypothesis is helpful (the distinction between exporting from the attribute table vs the layer), unless confirmed this isn't really an answer. Also, if you believe the question to be a duplicate of another, you can flag it as such, during the process of which it will ask you which one and link to it. All of this would be best as a comment rather than posting as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you checked box `"skip attribute creation"` in `save as layer dialogue box`.

[image: save as layer dialogue box -QGIS]

Comment: This is a good observation. But since the OP says all the field names are present, it would seem the attributes *were* created--but just not copied into the output.