# How to copy elements and attributes?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, qgis-2

I need to copy many elements (and their attributes) from a shapefile and paste to another one. If I use copy/paste functions it pastes only the polygons but not the attributes.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Would http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26198/how-to-create-a-new-layer-from-a-selection-in-qgis work?