# Creating new layer using selection from attribute table in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, layers

How do I create a new layer using a selection from an attribute table in QGIS 2.10.1?

Previous answers on this topic do not help -perhaps because they relate to older versions of QGIS

Comment: What were the previous answers on this topic?  It is best to always link to any relevant earlier Q&As.

Comment: The way to create a new layer from selected features has not changed since *at least* QGIS 1.7 (see [How to create a new layer from a selection in QGIS?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/26199/64955) which describes the same method as the one explained by ahmadhanb below).

Answer (score 5):

After selecting the features you want, go to `Layer -> Save as -> Under Encoding check 'save only selected feature'`. A shortcut to the above process right-click the layer you selected features from, then go to `save as -> Under Encoding check 'save only selected feature'`

Comment: When I try this I get the following error message: "Export to vector file failed. Error: creation of layer failed (OGR error:Failed to create file XXX.shp: Permission denied)"

Comment: Try to update  QGIS. IT IS NOW 2.14.15 for LTR  and 2.18.9 for latest version

Comment: I worked out that you also have to click on "Browse" and select location to save the file to.