# Creating layer from selection in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I have a point layer (bus stops), and I want to select the ones that are going to be changed (they have a common attribute to select them). I copy the selection (either ctrl+c or with the menu button) and choose the option "Edit > Paste Features as > Memory vector layer"

I choose the correct CRS (i've tried other CRS) and i create a memory vector layer (i've also tried to save it as a vector layer).

And the result is that the layer I get doesn't have any attribute:

[image: No attributes]

I've done this a lot of times, and I've never had this issue.
But this time, it doesn't work.

Just to clarify, the layer only has 300 points more or less, so it is not a limit problem. I've also tried to create a layer from selection on other layers, but still the same problem. It seems something has broken (yesterday everything worked fine).

Any idea why this is happening?

(QGIS 2.8.3 on Windows 7)

Comment: Try to update your QGIS version to the latest long term release which is 2.14.7 LTR, and see if this update can solve your problem.

Comment: I already have this in mind, the problem is I'm in the middle of a project and I prefer to finish it with this (outdated) version.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the copy past issue in 2.18

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [creating new layer using selection from attribute table in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/190260/85267) via `Layer -> Save as -> Under Encoding check 'save only selected feature`.

Comment: You are my hero! That worked perfectly! 
But i still have curiosity about what happened and why the other method doesn't work anymore...