# Saving selection as new layer after using array for filter expression in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, select-by-attribute, json, extract, qgsvectorlayer

I am selecting features based on whether `"ZIP_CODE"` value is found in an array. I am getting matches with the following:

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()

array = [93013, 35007]
matches = 0

for i in array:
    expression = ('ZIP_CODE = ' + str(i))
    request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(expression)
    for f in layer.getFeatures(request):
        matches += 1

print(matches)
```

Which works. How do I save this selection as a new Layer? If I have a JSON file I want to iterate over instead of this simple array, do I just load it in as per standard Pythonic way with:

```py
with open(json_file) as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)
```

Comment: have a look to the class: QgsVectorFileWriter and the method writeAsVectorFormat where you can set the option onlySelected (bool = False) – write only selected features of layer -> https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsVectorFileWriter.html#qgis.core.QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Please [Edit] this Question to focus on one question.

Answer (score 3):

I figured most of it out by changing the for loop to collect those selected features and save it to an in-memory layer as below:

```
for i in array:
    expression = ('ZIP_CODE = ' + str(i))
    selection = layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(expression))
    layer.selectByIds([k.id() for k in selection],QgsVectorLayer.AddToSelection)

memory_layer = layer.materialize(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFids(layer.selectedFeatureIds()))
```

and then just saved that new in-memory layer out in the UI dashboard by right clicking on it. It is a one off so this worked for me

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your solution by doing away with the loop altogether.

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()

array = [35007, 93013]

# check ZIP_CODE against multiple values by using the `in` operator
# an `f string` is used to insert the array directly into the string
# the list is cast as a tuple so that the array is surrounded by parentheses () in the expression - instead of []
expression = f'ZIP_CODE in {tuple(array)}'

# can also use string concatenation as you have done
#expression = 'ZIP_CODE in ' + str(tuple(array)) 

req = QgsFeatureRequest()
req.setFilterExpression(expression)

# materialize the feature request directly, no need to select the features!
memory_layer = layer.materialize(req)
memory_layer.setName('filtered layer')   # name is same as `layer` by default so rename it

p = QgsProject.instance()
p.addMapLayer(memory_layer)
```

Answer (score 1):

Extending great answers from @Matt, @OP himself, and also solutions mentioned in these threads: [Creating temporary layer out of selection in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/260467/creating-temporary-layer-out-of-selection-in-qgis/448360#448360) and [Duplicating layer in memory using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/205947/duplicating-layer-in-memory-using-pyqgis/429671#429671). I would like to mention the native QGIS tool for dealing with selected features, i.e. ["Extract selected features"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#qgissaveselectedfeatures).

So, after selection, one could proceed with the following script:

```py
# imports
import processing
from qgis.core import QgsProject

layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("YOUR_LAYER_NAME")[0]

if layer.selectedFeatureCount() > 0:
    params = {'INPUT' : layer, 'OUTPUT' : 'D:/path/to/the/selection.gpkg' }
    processing.runAndLoadResults("native:saveselectedfeatures", params)
```

The above script should:

1. Create a GeoPackage under this path `D:/path/to/the/selection.gpkg`
2. Load this GeoPackage to your project

BTW, one can get a number of *"matches"* by means of the [`selectedFeatureCount()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a482a410d199e91a17be28cc32eb51092) method of the `QgsVectorLayer` class.