# How to create a new point file containing selected points?

Tags: qgis, select

Using QGIS 2.16.3, I have uploaded a point dataset. Using the attribute table, I have made a selection of several points, and would like to create a new point layer containing only the selected points. I have consulted:
  [How to create a new layer from a selection in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26198/how-to-create-a-new-layer-from-a-selection-in-qgis)
Problematically, my menu selection is somewhat different form the one here, and I can not choose 'Save selection as'. Is there any other way to choose the selection?

[image: Menu selection options]

Comment: Try going to `Save As...` from the menu then there should be a `Save only selected features` option. Alternatively, use the `Save selected features` tool from the **Processing Toolbox**.

Comment: Most welcome but the post you linked to had an answer which described the `Save As...` method so this question may be flagged as a duplicate :)