# Create filter expression by selected elements?

Tags: qgis-3, features, select, definition-query

Is it possible to automatically create a filter expression for the Query Builder by selected elements?

Comment: So, you manually want to select all elements of interest in order to create a query which does the same? Why?

Comment: I have a giant set of line features (around 9000), each with a unique name. When I just want to display special features (let's say 20), or filter for geoprocessing, then normally I have to write each name in a query: `"Field1" In ('Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3', ... 'NameX')`. So what I want is to select the features in the canvas and then filter the selected features, or automatically build a filter expression from them.

Comment: In ArcGIS you can right-click and select "Create Layer From Selected Features" to create a temporary layer. I dont Think this is possible in QGIS without saving the features to disk, see [Creating new layer from selection in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26198/creating-new-layer-from-selection-in-qgis). Im sure it is possible using pyqis though.

Comment: Geoprocessing is possible for selected features only.