# How to split BIG 4GB GPX file into many?

Tags: gpx

How to split such file into many smaller ones ? It contains around 6 million different routes.
I want to split 1 file with 6 million features (line string paths) so I have 6 million features. 1 feature - 1 gpx file.

Comment: Do you need to store vector data in GPX format or can you switch to other formats? I highly recommend to convert the data to GeoPackage format using QGIS: https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html

Comment: @Mr. Che  Originally I used Qgis to obtain the data, then I wanted to extract it to separate gpx files but Qgis allowed me to save it all to one file. 
I need gpx unfortunately.

Comment: If you are trying to save selected features - check out this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/26199/35561

Comment: @Mr. Che This doesnt work. It still saves into 1 file.

Comment: Before saving features were selected? Does the saved file contain the selected features? You have to edit your answer and specify what do you mean by "split".

Comment: Check out this tool: https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#split-vector-layer

Comment: @Mr. Che , yes, split vector layer works good. However it saves each feature with extension gpkg, for example:
file_name_5c8e0d6f-5aca-49ef-a43b-3f643cc87935.gpx.gpkg
How to make it gpx back again ?

Comment: Try to use: https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/vectorconversion.html#convert-format

Comment: @Mr. Che I need little help here. 
Conversion requires a layer and there is no option to save into many gpx files... 
Whilst Split vector layer saves it into that weird format. 
How to combine them two into one ?
I'm new to GIS btw.

Comment: Have you tried "Extract/clip by extent" tool from the Processing toolbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use [Split vector layer](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#split-vector-layer) tool save each feature in separate file.
2. Convert them back to gpx using [Convert format](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/vectorconversion.html#convert-format) tool. Use Batch processing (right click on the tool).

Comment: Thanks it works. For 17 features. But I will have 6 Million of them.... That will blow up my pc....